How does $\dot{q}_i p_i - H = \dot{Q}_i P_i - K + \frac{d}{dt}F$ will give the same EL and EoM for corresponding coords?
How does $\dot{q}_i p_i - H = \dot{Q}_i P_i - K + \frac{d}{dt}F$ give the same Euler-Lagrange equations and Equations of motion (EoM) for corresponding coordinates and allow us to determine a canonical transformation? Here $K$ is the Kamiltonian.
Here is the logic my professor used in class:
Recall the the Euler-Lagrange equations are invariant when:

$L(q, \dot{q}, t) = L(Q,\dot{Q},t) $, where $Q = Q(q,t)$ a point transformation.
$L'(q, \dot{q}, t) = L + \frac{d}{dt}F(q,t).$

Thus $L(q,\dot{q},t) = L(Q,\dot{Q}, t)  + \frac{d}{dt}F(q,t) $ will have the same EoM.
Using L = $\dot{q}_i p_i - H$ we can then write that
$\dot{q}_i p_i - H = \dot{Q}_i P_i - K + \frac{d}{dt}F$ will give the same equations of motion.
This logic seems completely errornous to me since

The generating function $F$ can be a function of $p$ and by invertibility a function of $\dot{q}$. But 2) only holds for $F = F(q,t)$. Never are generating functions restricted only to $q$

Combining 1. and 2. together in this way seems erronous. Perhaps it is meant that $L(q,\dot{q},t) = L(Q,\dot{Q}, t)  + \frac{d}{dt}F(q,t) $ is also just a point transformation so it does not change the Euler lagrange equations?



Ok, but you should edit all definitions into the question itself, also have you made any attempt to show that you can derive the same results with the untransformed lagrangian, that is go through all the steps and see how it isn't supposed to change?

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/560216/2451
